# Extracting unicode data from url source by xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, unicode, lxml

I want to extract unicode form

```
<div class="" id="messageContent">\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1</div>
```

What I tried is:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
post_data=...
post_response=requests.post(url='http://example.com/', data=post_data)
out=post_response.text
tree=html.fromstring(out)
print out.xpath('//div/[@id="messageContent"]/text()')
```

## Update

Then the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1447, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:41728)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 321, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117734)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 239, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116911)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116780)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

I want the output from `messageContent`:

```
\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1
```

Comment: `out` is the text, `tree` is the ElementTree object. Looks like a simple typo to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear: the variable `out` stores a unicode object, not an object with a `xpath` attribute. You probably just mixed up `out` and `tree`

```
print out # will give you the whole text
print tree.xpath(...)  # will probably print what you were looking for
```

It does not have anything to do with the "unicode data" you are trying to extract.

Comment: Yeeah Thank you... I was confused... imagine I said: `print tree.xpath(...)` ..The error is `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`

Comment: Sometimes we overlook the most obvious things :). If it helped, consider the upvote and mark as answer.

Comment: I can't get `\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1`

Comment: That is another question actually. The problem is that the text in `out` is not parseable as xml. Print `out` and try to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to say `tree.xpath(...)`.